# how to get drupal menus work permanently

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

so I'm using drupal and despite not changing the entries in the hook_menus often my menu would suddenly stop appearing and I have to keep on clearing cache/rebuilding menus to get them to reappear despite the fact that no changes were made to any hook_menus...

anyone know why this could be happening and how to prevent it from doing so?

Comment: Without knowing more details... is it possible that a module you installed or some recent change you made is causing the issue?  Or has this always been the case from the start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know what couese the problem because i don know what you hav did exactly.... but try to add the following code in somewhere ..mmm for example ur page.tpl.php theme file

```
include_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
menu_cache_clear_all()
```

if its not worked with you try this

```
include_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
drupal_flush_all_caches();
```

Comment: If you leave that code in there long-term your caches are going to be constantly cleared, which won't be fun for the server.

Comment: its a fast solution...but not a permanent one.. he should  know where is exactly the problem or even give us more details of what lead to this problem...its better then no solution anyway..